# PhoneGap FileTransfer undefined iOS

Tags: cordova

After following the instructions here: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer I have the following function:

```
function testUpload(imageURI) {

  var options = new FileUploadOptions();
  options.fileKey="file";
  options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
  options.mimeType="image/jpeg";

  var params = {};
  params.value1 = "test";
  params.value2 = "param";


  options.params = params;
  alert("This will show");
  alert(typeof(FileTransfer)); // "undefined"
  var ft = new FileTransfer();
  alert("This will not show...");
  ft.upload(imageURI, encodeURI("my.server/.php"), win, fail, options);

}
```

Since FileTransfer() is undefined the upload progress do not proceed. But shouldn't I get an error while calling FileUploadOptions() as well then? I tried to Google for libraries etc I need to load, but couldn't find anything.

I guess I'm doing something wrong when implementing the plugin. I've loaded it using:

```
$ cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-file.git
```

And of-course, added it to my config.xml:

```
<feature name="File">
  <param name="ios-package" value="CDVFile" />
</feature>
<feature name="FileTransfer">
  <param name="ios-package" value="CDVFileTransfer" />
</feature>
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 5):

I finally just figured this out. You also have to install the FileTransfer plugin, in addition to the File plugin you already installed.

```
cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-file-transfer.git
```